# Is there a way to have a more complex rule in workflow section?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We are looking for a way to identify a merge request event in more detail. For example we want to execute a pipeline only if it was triggered by an upstream job (webhook at a merge request event) and only if the action is "merge". So no execution on "open", "updated", "closed" and so on.

Is there a way to do this?

What we would like to have is something like this:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_TRIGGERED && "$(cat $TRIGGER_PAYLOAD | jq -r '.object_attributes.action') == 'merge'"
      when: always
    - when: never
```

None of the predefined Gitlab Variables seem to fit our needs.